# Preserve some gitignored files while running git clean -X

Tags: git, git-clean

I'm working with a repository where you often want to do a clean build. This causes the build script to issue a `git clean -Xdff` which will remove all files that match patterns in `.gitignore`. I want some files that are ignored by Git (e.g. `.project` from Eclipse) to stick around after the clean.

I've tried adding the `-e` flag for "exclude" but that doesn't seem to help given that we're purposely cleaning the things that Git ignores.

To see for yourself:

```
~$ mkdir testrepo && cd testrepo
~/testrepo$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/turbulencetoo/testrepo/.git/
~/testrepo$ echo ".project" > .gitignore
~/testrepo$ touch .project
~/testrepo$ git clean -Xn
Would remove .project
~/testrepo$ git clean -Xn -e .project
Would remove .project
```

What alteration would you recommend to the `git clean` call (or surrounding code) in my local build script in order to preserve my `.project` file during a clean build?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Warning this solution as stated by @turbulencetoo

*will have the side effect of deleting other untracked files in your working set (e.g. newSourceFile.c) if you haven't added them yet.*

---

I think your problem is you're using `X` instead of `x` flag, you should be using this instead ,

```
git clean -xn -e .project
```

Comment: This does work to save the file, but it will have the side effect of deleting other untracked files in your working set (e.g. `newSourceFile.c`) if you haven't `add`ed them yet.

Comment: @turbulencetoo Isn't what `git clean` is for ?

Comment: depends on the use case, I guess. In this case the `-X` was used to make sure that only specific patterns of files get cleaned.

Comment: @turbulencetoo added clarification.

Answer (score 2):

From [`git clean`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clean), only `-x` allows `-e` files to be *considered*.
Meaning `.project` would be deleted either way (`-X` with ignore rules or `-x -e`)

> if the `-x` option is specified, ignored files are also removed.
>   `-e <pattern>`: In addition to those found in `.gitignore` (per directory) and `$GIT_DIR/info/exclude`, also consider these patterns to be in the set of the ignore rules in effect.
>   `-X`: Remove only files ignored by Git

As commented, the documentation is confusing for `-e`.